# how to find if any character in a string is a number in python? .isnumeric and .isdigit isn't working

Tags: python

I need to determine if there are alphabetic and numeric characters in a string. My code for testing the alphabetic one seems to work fine, but numeric is only working if all of the characters are a digit, not if any.

The alphabetic code that works:

```
from curses.ascii import isalnum, isalpha, isdigit

password = input("Enter your password: ")

def contains_alphabetic():
    for i in password:
        if isalpha(i):
            print("Valid")
            return True
        else:
            print("Invalid")
            return False

contains_alphabetic()
```

This returns "Valid" if at least one of the characters is alphabetic, and "Invalid" if none of them are, which is what I want.

```
def contains_numeric():
    for j in password:
        if isdigit(j):
            print("Valid")
            return True
        else:
            print("Invalid")
            return False

contains_numeric()
```

This only returns "Valid" if all of the characters are numeric, not if at least one is. How do I fix this?

Also, I tried using is.numeric() instead of is.digit() and it wouldn't even import.

Comment: `contains_alphabetic` returns `True` for `"a1"` and False for `"1a"`; `contains_numeric` returns `True` for `"1a"` and False for `"a1"`.  Using a debugger will help explain why.

Comment: No, your functions only test the first character of `password`.

Comment: You need the `return False` to be ***after*** the loop...

Comment: @quamrana how do i get it to test all of the characters?

Comment: Use the `all()` or `any()` functions instead of a loop.

Comment: I'm unclear what you want to test for. Do you want both functions to return `True` if any character is correct?

Comment: Try using regular expressions to implement your requirements. For example, `bool(re.search(r'\d','password123'))`.

Comment: Also it is not necessary to import anything. `str` already has [`isalnum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalnum) method

Comment: Both of your `contains_XXX` functions return on the first iteration, so they only test the first character.

Comment: @quamrana i need to to verify whether or not the entered password meets the requirements which include must contain a numeric character and an alphabetic character. i'm not allowed to use regular expressions or lists, loops and string methods only

Comment: Ok, that's simple. Just remove the 'else:' statements and unindent the return False.

Comment: Run the code in your head (or on paper): you iterate over each character. Now you check if it's numeric/alphabetic. If it is you return True if not you return False. That's it, You never check the other characters. What you *want* is to return True if it is numeric/alphabetic ***and only return False if the loop ended without a match***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments have pointed out, both your `contains_alphabetic` and `contains_numeric` functions don't do what you think they're doing, because they terminate prematurely - during the very first iteration. You start a loop, inspect the current character (which will be the first character of the string during the first iteration of the loop), and immediately return something from the function based on that single character, which of course terminates the loop and the function.

Other suggestions: There's no need to import things from `curses`. Strings already have `isalpha` and `isdigit` predicates available. Additionally, it's probably a good idea to have your functions accept a string parameter to iterate over.

If the idea is to return `True` if any of the characters in a string satisfy a condition/predicate, and `False` otherwise (if none of the characters satisfy the condition), then the following would be a working implementation:

```
def contains_alpha(string):
    for char in string:
        if char.isalpha():
            return True # return True as soon as we see a character that satisfies the condition
    return False # Notice the indentation - we only return False if we managed to iterate over every character without returning True
```

Alternatively:

```
def contains_alpha(string):
    found = False
    for char in string:
        if char.isalpha():
            found = True
            break
    return found
```

Or:

```
def contains_alpha(string):
    for char in string:
        if char.isalpha():
            break
    else: # Notice indentation - special for-else syntax: If we didn't break out of the loop, execute the else
        return False
    return True
```

Or:

```
def contains_alpha(string):
    return any(char.isalpha() for char in string)
```

Comment: To take it one step further: Add an argument to the function: `contains(string, func)` and then do inside `if func(char)` so you don't need to replicate the functions. Just call once with `contains(password, str.isalph)` and once `contains(password, str.isnum)`